# Reading large text files into MATLAB

Tags: matlab, import, text-files

I'm trying to write a function to read multiple (1000+) text files ('.txt') into MATLAB. A snippit of one file is shown below. The actual file has the same columns but with ~150 000 rows.

```
Start, Serial, DeviceId, RunNumber, Date, Real, Elapsed, X, EcgVal, EcgStatus, CapnoVal, CapnoStatus, P1Val, P1Status, P2Val, P2Status, P3Val, P3Status, Spo2Val, Spo2Status, CprDepth, CprFrequency, CprStatus, CprWaveVal, FiltEcgVal, FiltEcgStatus, Ecg2Val, Ecg2Status, Ecg3Val, Ecg3Status, Ecg4Val, Ecg4Status
2013-01-01 23:51:12, 00017711, TEMS ACP272, , 01-01-2013, 23:51:12.000, 00:00:00.000, 41275.993889, 0.000000, -1, 0.000000, 0, 0.000000, 0, 0.000000, 0, 0.000000, 0, 0.000000, 0, 0.000000, 0, 0, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1, 0.000000, 1, 0.000000, 1, 0.000000, 1
2013-01-01 23:51:12, 00017711, TEMS ACP272, , 01-01-2013, 23:51:12.008, 00:00:00.008, 41275.993889, 0.000000, -1, 0.000000, 0, 0.000000, 0, 0.000000, 0, 0.000000, 0, 0.000000, 0, 0.000000, 0, 0, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1, 0.000000, 1, 0.000000, 1, 0.000000, 1
2013-01-01 23:51:12, 00017711, TEMS ACP272, , 01-01-2013, 23:51:12.016, 00:00:00.016, 41275.993889, 0.000000, -1, 0.000000, 0, 0.000000, 0, 0.000000, 0, 0.000000, 0, 0.000000, 0, 0.000000, 0, 0, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1, 0.000000, 1, 0.000000, 1, 0.000000, 1
2013-01-01 23:51:12, 00017711, TEMS ACP272, , 01-01-2013, 23:51:12.024, 00:00:00.024, 41275.993889, 0.000000, -1, 0.000000, 0, 0.000000, 0, 0.000000, 0, 0.000000, 0, 0.000000, 0, 0.000000, 0, 0, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1, 0.000000, 1, 0.000000, 1, 0.000000, 1
```

I've tried the obvious approaches (csvread, dlmread, importdata) without success. When I open this file using the 'ImportData' function I get:

```
þS
```

followed by 5 blank lines. Using

```
fid = fopen('TEST.txt','r');
fgetl(fid)
```

I find that there is an empty row between each data row and that there is a space between each character.

I've also tried using the textscan function as follows

```
fid = fopen('TEST.txt','r');
c = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', ',')
```

but this returns an empty cell.

An alternative that does work is to open the file in Excel and save it as a CSV file. However, given that I am trying to do this for 1000+ files, this is not feasible.

Any comments, suggestions, or advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

UPDATE:

The following seems to work:

```
data = textscanu('TEST.txt');
str=textscan(data{1},'%s','Delimiter',',')
```

I will try to write this up in general to read the entire file, skip blank lines, and organize all the columns.

Comment: And store everything  starting from the second line those 32 columns into a `N x 32` sized cell array for each text file?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. I'm not super picky about the format - I can reformat/organize the data once it's imported.

Comment: how do you save your txt files to begin with? is it possible they are encoded in some 16bits per char instead of 8bits per char? some unicode perhaps?

Comment: The text files are downloaded from a machine (a defibrillator in fact) so I have no control over how they are saved. It is entirely possible that they are in unicode or have some strange encoding.

Comment: So, it appears there are 33 entries in each row, please make sure of that.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach #1:** With `importdata` -

```
%// Import text data as string cells, assuming file1 is the path to text file
data = importdata(file1,'')

%// Split columns based on the delimiter: ' '
split_data = cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x,' ') , data(2:end),'Uni',0)

%// Gather data into a N x number_of_entries cell array
out_data = vertcat(split_data{:})

%// Remove the commas after each entry (if so desired)
out_data = cellfun(@(x) strrep(x,',','') , out_data,'Uni',0)

%// Remove the sixth columns that had extra commas
out_data(:,6) = []
```

**Approach #2:** With `textscan` -

```
%// Read entire text data into a cell of a cell array, 
%// assuming file1 is the path to text file
fileID = fopen(file1,'r');
onecell_data = textscan(fileID,'%s','Delimiter','\n','HeaderLines',1);
fclose(fileID);

%// Unpack one level of data to have N x 1 sized cell array
data = [onecell_data{:}]

%// Split columns based on the delimiter: ' '
split_data = cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x,' ') , data(2:end),'Uni',0)

%// Gather data into a N x number_of_entries cell array
out_data = vertcat(split_data{:})

%// Remove the commas after each entry (if so desired)
out_data = cellfun(@(x) strrep(x,',','') , out_data,'Uni',0)

%// Remove the sixth columns that had extra commas
out_data(:,6) = []
```

Comment: @DrDunkenstein What's your MATLAB version & OS? Can you try this instead : `data = importdata(file1,'%s')`?

Comment: I have MATLAB 2012b and Windows 7 Ultimate. Just going to a meeting but will try that afterwards. Also, see the update above!

Comment: @DrDunkenstein Check out the just added new approach.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. For some reason this doesn't work either, 'onecell_data' is an empty cell array.

Comment: @DrDunkenstein Could be a file specific issue. If you could share, upload somewhere and link it here. Sorry otherwise.